# How to convert json to proto message format in Javascript client side?

Tags: reactjs, envoyproxy, proto, protoc, grpc-web

I need to send a JSON as request to a grpc API via Envoy. Currently, I am using setter functions from protoc auto generated code. Is there any way to directly convert json (even, deeply nested ones) to proto message and send it as request?

Here's the proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package movieDetails;

message Category {
    string code = 1;
    repeated float ratings = 2;
    bool liked = 3;
}

message MovieRequest {
    string ping = 1;
    Category sample = 2;
}

message MovieResponse {
    string title = 1;
    string desc = 2;
    repeated int32 numbers = 3;
    repeated Category sample = 4;
}

service MovieDetailService {
    rpc getDetails(MovieRequest) returns (MovieResponse);
}
```

I used protoc to auto generate *_pb.js files.

By proto message I mean data in this format.

```
{
  "wrappers_": {
    "2": {
      "wrappers_": null,
      "arrayIndexOffset_": -1,
      "array": [
        "XY",
        [
          0.1,
          0.6,
          0.9
        ],
        true
      ],
      "pivot_": 1.7976931348623157e+308,
      "convertedPrimitiveFields_": {
        "2": true
      }
    }
  },
  "arrayIndexOffset_": -1,
  "array": [
    "Mission Impossible",
    [
      "XY",
      [
        0.1,
        0.6,
        0.9
      ],
      true
    ]
  ],
  "pivot_": 1.7976931348623157e+308,
  "convertedPrimitiveFields_": {}
}
```

for corresponding JSON

```
{
  "ping": "Mission Impossible",
  "sample": {
    "code": "XY",
    "ratingsList": [
      0.1,
      0.6,
      0.9
    ],
    "liked": true
  }
}
```

This my React code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const { MovieDetailServiceClient } = require('./grpc/sample_grpc_web_pb');
const { MovieRequest, serializeBinaryToWriter , Category } = require('./grpc/sample_pb');

var client = new MovieDetailServiceClient('http://localhost:9090', null, null);
console.log(client)
class App extends Component {
   callGrpcService = async () => {
    const request = new MovieRequest();
    request.setPing('Mission Impossible');

    const cat = new Category();
    cat.setCode('XY')
    cat.setRatingsList([0.1, 0.6, 0.9])
    cat.setLiked(true)


    const catJson = {code: 'XY', ratings: [0.1, 0.4], liked: false}
    console.log(catJson)// CAN THIS BE DIRECTLY ENCODED AND SEND REQUEST??

    await request.setSample(cat)
    console.log(':', request.toObject())
    client.getDetails(request, {}, (err, response) => {
      if (response == null) {
        console.log('BUG:',err)
      }else {
        console.log(response.getTitle(), response.getDesc(), response.getNumbersList(), response.getSampleList())
        console.log(response.toObject())
        console.log(response.getSampleList().map(it => it.getRatingsList()))
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <button style={{padding:10}} onClick={this.callGrpcService}>Click for grpc request</button>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what do you mean by "proto message"?

Comment: @Lelouch proto message is a part of Google's ProtoBuf which is platform independent messaging service

Comment: @Lelouch I've edited my question for better understanding.